# Is it considered bad practice to access module variables from function?

Tags: python, function, variables, module, global-variables

In Python it is possible for functions to access module variables as the follows:

```
def pow(a):
    return a**b

a = 3
b = 2
print(pow(a))
```

Is this considered bad practice?

The obvious alternative would be to explicitly pass all arguments to functions:

```
def pow(a, b):
    return a**b

a = 3
b = 2
print(pow(a, b))
```

I am using the first form as a way to limit the number of parameters passed to a function, and I was wondering whether this is considered bad practice.

Comment: yes and no. it is not a very clean coding style but at the same it, *if you know what you are doing*, and you have a reason for it, it is ok. Now, specifically for the example you posted above, I do not see a reason.

Comment: I don't see any problem here. It's better though to make functions self-contained, but it's not a crime to use globals inside functions, globals are globals. The answer depends on your application. I can't even say if eating ice-cream in a cold day is a bad habit.

Comment: At the end I used the second alternative. To limit the number of parameters I have created a class encapsulating them. Still, I am having some global module constants defined at the top of the module for all functions (I see no problem in that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible; but use the `global` or `nonlocal` keywords if you do this.

```
LOGGER = logging.getLogger('FooLogger')
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def log_this(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global LOGGER # this is in the global namespace
        nonlocal func # this is from the parent function
        retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
        LOGGER.info('%s(*%s, **%s)=%s', func.__name__, args, kwargs, retval)
        return retval
    return wrapper

@log_this
def cube(base, *, mod=None):
    return pow(base, 3)

>>> cube(4)
INFO:FooLogger:cube(*(4,), **{})=64
64
>>> cube(4, mod=7)
INFO:FooLogger:cube(*(4,), **{'mod': 7})=1
1
```

But it's generally better to pass a variable explicitly to a function. That enhances readability, and reduces ambiguity in the function's purpose. Consider the following:

```
MIN_SIZE = 5

def check_size(collection):
    global MIN_SIZE
    return len(collection) > MIN_SIZE

>>> check_size([1, 2, 3])
False
```

At first glance, I see that `check_size` is called, but what size is it checking against? If I didn't know, I'd have to search for it. This is a readability problem that will only serve to confuse more, as the program grows.

```
MIN_SIZE = 5

def check_size(collection, size):
    return len(v) > n

>>> check_size(range(10), MIN_SIZE)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your usage context, since:

1. The only way to access imported modules is to reference their namespace in the module scope:

:

```
import foo
import bar_var from bar as bvar

def myfun(a):
    return foo.foo_func(a)
    # foo is in module namespace, nobody adds it to the caller's signature

def myfun2(b):
    myfun(b) 

>>> myfun2(bvar) # returns foo.foo_func(bvar)
```

2. Also relying on python lexical scope rules is the only way to implement closures:

:

```
def outerfun(a):

    def innerfun():
        return a

    return innerfun

>>> inner_alias = outerfun("foo")
>>> inner_alias()
"foo"
```

So follow best practices for: making code easy to read and managing global variables/namespaces, specifically remembering that mutable datastructures will be modified regardless of whether they were passed in the signature or not:

:

```
L = []

def foo(alist):
    alist.append(1)
    return alist

def foo2():
    L.append(1)
    return L

>>> foo(L)
[1]
>>> L
[1] #!!! (lists are mutable and python passes by assignment)
>>> foo2()
[1, 1]
>>> L
[1, 1]
```

P.S. In OOP with Python, instance methods are explicitly defined with the instance as the first argument (but automatically implicitly called with this argument), exposing the class namespace to the method:

:

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self): # the first argument must be the instance
        # __init__ is the constructor which we are overriding here
        self.inst_var1 = 1
        # initialize an instance var

    def add(self, i): # the first argument must be the instance
        if i <= 0:
            raise ValueError("i must be a positive number!")
            # But ValueError is a module global, because Exceptions are in global namespace
        return self.inst_var1 + i

>>> myclass_inst = myClass()
>>> myclass_inst.inst_var1
1
>>> myclass_inst.add(1) 
# python automatically binds first argument to `myclass_inst`, 
# as if myclass_inst.add = functools.partial(myclass_inst.add, myclass_inst)
2
```